# Google BigQuery select max for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, google-bigquery

I have a problem with my BigQuery select, I need to get the max value for the column (students) for each day.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM timestamp) as date, ARRAY_LENGTH(student_ids) as students from analytics.daily_active_students_count order by timestamp desc
```

| Row | Date | Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-16 | 72 |
| 2 | 2022-05-16 | 33 |
| 3 | 2022-05-16 | 12 |
| 4 | 2022-05-15 | 10 |
| 5 | 2022-05-15 | 84 |
| 6 | 2022-05-15 | 8 |
| 7 | 2022-05-14 | 92 |
| 8 | 2022-05-14 | 105 |
| 9 | 2022-05-14 | 12 |

Query should remove duplicated rows for days and take only rows with max number of students.

I want my output looks like this:

| Row | Date | Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-16 | 72 |
| 2 | 2022-05-15 | 84 |
| 3 | 2022-05-14 | 105 |

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my backend used different timezone. I solved this issue with casting timestamp:

```
DATE(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP, "Europe/Zagreb")) as date
```